# How should I store passwords locally for a multi-user application?

Tags: delphi, passwords, delphi-7

I want to create a multi-user application, but I don't know how to save and read encrypted passwords.

```
procedure SavePass(Password: WideString);
var
  Pass: TIniFile;
begin
  Pass := TIniFile.Create(ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName, '.PASS'));
  Pass.WriteString('Users', 'USERNAME', Password);
  Pass.Free;
```

The passwords must be stored on the computer.
This works but it's stupid to save passwords using this.
Hashing passwords would be also good.

Comment: why not use the default facilities in Windows for users and passwords? If you're on a domain which would be normal for a multi-user program I'd use the domain server and the functions available for authenticating users on that. If you're on a single machine I'd authenticate against the user table on that machine. If you don't know how to to that, ask a question like: `How to authenticate a user in a domain (active directory)`.

Comment: You have another issue: do not store anything in the application directory. It is not writable but by users with high privileges, and it is readable by every computer user. Vista and 7 will redirect bad applications, but it's better to write well-behaved applications, and store data in a more secure place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the connecting software accepts hashed passwords, it's not going to stop people who steal the hashed passwords from connecting. All it will do is hide what the real password is.

Furthermore, if the software that you're connecting to does not accept hashed passwords (database, website, ...), you're going to have to store your password in such a way that you can get it back to its original state. A hashed version is not going to help you there.

If you want to scramble your storage so that humans cannot read the file, you could use `Windows.EncryptFile()` and `Windows.DecryptFile()`. In newer Delphi's that's neatly wrapped into `IoUtils.TFile.Encrypt()` and `IoUtils.TFile.Decrypt`.

If you really want to stop others from reading the cleartext version of your password, you're going to have to use some encryption with a key. Where do you store that key then?That would defeat the whole purpose of storing a password in the first place. It's better to prevent access by other users by using user privileges to the file system for example, because anything you or your software can do, a "hacker" can do if he has the same privileges.

Comment: Robrok, if you don't understand an answer, then please don't accept it as the *correct* answer. When you do that, the people interested in answering questions stop paying attention, and the people interested in learning the answer are left just as confused as you are. If you have more questions, please ask.

Comment: @Robrok, also consider adding some salt, for example: HashedPassword := Md5('SomeSalt' + PlainPassword);

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to not use passwords in your application at all, unless you really need to. The user experience of having yet another password to enter & remember is usually not needed.

What I do for my applications is default to using the domain and user name of the current user as the identification. The user has already logged on with a password, or more secure system if they want it. Only by logging on can they be that current user. My server then accepts that as their identification.

Variations on this include optionally passing the machine name too, so that the same user is treated differently on different computers (when they need to use more than once computer at once). And of course you can still allow a normal password if you want to.

Comment: Are you saying you're simply sendin domain/user and not taking advantage of Windows authentication?

Comment: Hmm, yes I'm saying I just send domain/user, but Windows took care of the authentication as I get the domain/user from the current user. Given that they can only get that by logging in, it works well. And saves anyone having to remember another password, or worse, entering it.

Comment: It's not a secure way to authenticate at all. Enumerating domain users is pretty simple. How does your server knows that's a logged on user? A Windows domain offers a sophisticated authentication mechanism, that relies on Kerberos tokens. If you can that's the way to authenticate. Otherwise there is the less secure NTLM.

Comment: @ldsandon Sure, if you can hack the comms protocol between the client and server, then you could I guess achieve access. In my app I use an encrypted channel, but even so I think most situations are safe enough and the user benefit of not having another password to manage is well worth it.

Comment: How do you establish a secure channel? Do you authenticate the endpoints?

Answer (score 2):

You should store hashed passwords. For example you could use one of the SHA algorithms from the [Delphi Cryptography Package](http://cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/DCPcrypt). When you check passwords hash the password that the user supplies and compare against that saved in the file.

Have you considered using Windows security rather than attempting to roll your own?

---

As an aside, you are liable to encounter problems writing to your program directory if your program resides under the program files directory and UAC is in use.

Comment: Not working because Delphi can`t find some components. SHA is good but please give other internet resource.

Comment: I dont wana install third party components to just run this demo. Thats the problem.

Comment: What other components do the demos require, Robrok? As far as I can tell, the two demo projects use nothing but standard Delphi components and the DCP units, which are the subject of the demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

There are hash and encryption routines in [Lockbox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tplockbox/). You should hash the password concatenated with a random 'salt' and store the salt and hash together. To make it harder for people to brute-force the hash - trying all likely passwords until the right one is found - you should iterate the hash. When the user subsequently enters their password to login take the salt from your store and hash it with their entered password, and iterate, and test the result against the hash you have stored. If they are the same they have given the correct password.

Comment: What da.. I just need two function but this program messed my computer.

Comment: Only for Delphi2007 and higher.

Comment: There is a Lockbox version 2 http://sourceforge.net/projects/tplockbox/files/TurboPower%20LockBox/LockBox%20version%202/2.07/ for older versions of Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

- As long as you can, don't store password, but hash them properly (use a salt, repeat hash n times, etc.) because rainbow table attacks are feasible and work well against poor chosen passwords and too simple hashing.
- If possible, take advantage of "integrated security". Use [Windows authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374735%28VS.85%29.aspx) to avoid storing passwords.
- If you really need to store a master password or the like, use Windows APIs like [CryptProtectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380261%28VS.85%29.aspx) to protect them locally.

Comment: @Robrok: sorry, I did not understand your request, be more specific, please.

Answer (score 0):

I think its best to keep user-specific settings in the Registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER. That will keep their settings all together and separate from other users' settings.

You'll automatically read the correct user's settings when you read from this area of the Registry, and you should store your password there as well. Yes, do encrypt it as David recommends. The Registry is easy for anyone to read using [RegEdit](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tools_regeditors.mspx?mfr=true).

Here's [an article on how you can write to and read from the registry](http://www.delphidabbler.com/tips/14).

Comment: @robrok what do your mean by easy to hack? Hashing sees to that.

Comment: Registry is easy to hack. My users gona cry! I want to use hashes!

Comment: Hash the values that you put in the registry and then there's no need for tears. On the other hand, if you think that a file in the same directory as your program can't be read by your users then you are misguided.

Comment: If you really don't like the registry, then use the file system instead. The important part is that you shouldn't store the passwords or the hashes in a *shared* location. If users can change their own passwords, then they must have permission to write to the password file. If they can do that, then they can change *any* password in that file. Alice could simply take the hash of her password and paste it over the hash of Bob's, and now Alice can log in as Bob because his password is the same as hers. Store Bob's password file in Bob's home directory where Alice can't get it.